# MongoDB PowerPC installation for Squeeze

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to install MongoDB on Debian Squeeze but I keep on getting an error: Error unable to located package, this I think is because I'm running on powerpc,  and on the internet Im only getting client-based installations for MongoDB. I was wondering if there is a server installation of MongoDB for Debian Squeeze PowerPC

Comment: Have you manually added the 10gen repo?

Comment: Why did you double post? http://serverfault.com/questions/478019/mongodb-powerpc-installation-for-squeeze

Comment: Yes I've add the 10 gen repo, but there is no powerpc version for this package under squeeze

Comment: sorry didnt know i double posted, 1st time user

Answer (score 2):

PowerPC is not officially supported by 10gen as it requires an Intel processor. While there have been some attempts to make it work -- they're not official.

One is [here](https://github.com/skrabban/mongo-nonx86), but it's very out of date (it's version is 1.8, and the current MongoDB version is 2.2).

The only supported way is to install the MongoDB on an Intel chipset, and use a driver for your favorite programming language to connect to the Database. Those apparently work on PowerPCs, etc. for many languages (according to the docs, but I've never tried it).