# Is it possible to Install MongoDB on I5/OS or IBMi server?

Tags: mongodb, zend-framework, ibm-midrange, nosql

I've done some research and it seems to imply that at least in 2011, the big endian/little endian problem prevented this since PPC cores were not compatible with the MongoDB server.

Has this changed? Or is it still impossible to get it running on an IBMi?

I'm confused since Zend seems to be supporting MongoDB now and is a major part of a web framework on an IBMi server.

It appears that using mongodb entirely on the IBMi is out of the question, is there a reliable NoSQL alternative with collections that would work? Perhaps one with a SAVF or RPM so it works out of the box?

Comment: Same problem, different computer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834488/mongodb-powerpc-installation-for-squeeze/14835427#14835427

Comment: (And Zend being supported on an IBMi server doesn't/shouldn't imply anything beyond the core framework is supported).

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling that would be happening. It's just that Zend made a big todo that they support MongoDB and that it's coming to the IBMi framework.

Comment: Almost wondering if it's worthwhile to ask _which_ noSQL systems with collections would work on a IBMi. I have a piece of software which has that requirements, but it's abstract enough I could probably replace the mongodb calls with something similar.

Comment: I'd guess they're making the driver work, not the database. Do you need the DB to run on the IBMi?

Comment: For the structure I want, optimally I'd want the DB to run on the IBMi so then I can create a savf for the whole package and be done with it.

Comment: mySQL and Zend DBi on IBM i actually use DB2 built into the operating system.  Is there something in particular that you need which DB2 is unsuitable for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MongoDB core server is little endian.

What you can do is have the drivers on the IBMi, as most of them are big endian, and the Mongo DB core servers on a little endian machine (AMD64 or Intel x86_64)

Comment: Yeah, that's what it looks like. Either that or I need to find an alternative with similar features.